# WSO2 ESB with Apache Load Balancer : Cert does not match for name

Tags: certificate, apache2, wso2, keystore, wso2-es

I have setup two esb servers (clustered) in different AWS instance, and I'm using Apache LB to do the load balancing part. I can't specify IP of other instance (or even the same instance) as it gives the following security issue which can be found in the `apapche error.log` But I can use localhost instead of the ip (for the same server) and it work. My apache config is below to the error log. I think I need to add a certificate to the esb's client store. If it is so please guide me how to do that (I tried specifying the IP as CN but no luck). Or else what am I doing wrong here?

```
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.803633 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] proxy_util.c(2610): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to 172.31.25.41:9443 (172.31.25.41)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.803645 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server esb.wso2.com:443)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.824988 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1381): [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none [subject: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / issuer: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / serial: 4B7E3782 / notbefore: Feb 19 07:02:26 2010 GMT / notafter: Feb 13 07:02:26 2035 GMT]
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.825028 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1381): [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none [subject: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / issuer: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / serial: 4B7E3782 / notbefore: Feb 19 07:02:26 2010 GMT / notafter: Feb 13 07:02:26 2035 GMT]
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846640 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1844): [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA (168/168 bits)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846678 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [esb.wso2.com:443] Cert does not match for name '172.31.25.41' [subject: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / issuer: CN=localhost,O=WSO2,L=Mountain View,ST=CA,C=US / serial: 4B7E3782 / notbefore: Feb 19 07:02:26 2010 GMT / notafter: Feb 13 07:02:26 2035 GMT]
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846684 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH02411: SSL Proxy: Peer certificate does not match for hostname 172.31.25.41
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846697 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] [remote 172.31.25.41:9443] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server esb.wso2.com:443)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846716 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 123.231.123.216:42158] AH01084: pass request body failed to 172.31.25.41:9443 (172.31.25.41)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846730 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] [client 123.231.123.216:42158] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846733 2015] [proxy_http:error] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] [client 123.231.123.216:42158] AH01097: pass request body failed to 172.31.25.41:9443 (172.31.25.41) from 123.231.123.216 ()
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846736 2015] [proxy:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] proxy_util.c(2035): AH00943: HTTPS: has released connection for (172.31.25.41)
[Tue Oct 06 15:55:52.846759 2015] [proxy_balancer:debug] [pid 16827:tid 140445371795200] mod_proxy_balancer.c(668): [client 123.231.123.216:42158] AH01176: proxy_balancer_post_request for (balancer://ssl.wso2.esb.com)
```

Apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName mgt.esb.wso2.com
 ProxyRequests off
 LogLevel debug
 ProxyPass / https://<pvt_ip>:9443/carbon/ *** I can use localhost here and it work
 ProxyPassReverse / https://<pvt_ip>:9443/carbon/
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mgt.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mgt.key
 SSLProxyEngine On
 SSLProxyVerify none
 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

I added the following configs to apache config file and could resolve the issue, but what it does is, it stops comparing the CN, PeerName or Expiration.